# How to call a class multiple times in an other class

Tags: java

I am creating a command-line java tool for generating RSA cryptography and applying a brute force attack on it. I have one class called RSA where I randomly generate the parameters, enter a text, encrypt it and decrypt it.

The second class is called BFRSA. It will be called to generate new random parameters, encrypt the same text and compare with the first encrypted one.

The problem is I can only call BFRSA once with the same variable name.

I need to call a class so please don't suggest turning it into a method.

```
BFRSA BS = new BFRSA();
```

Comment: How will you even call a class? You can only call methods.

Comment: It's not clear what exacltyt you want.. you can use static methods for multiple calls withoud instance of the class. Or do you need the same instance of the class more than once, you can make the class singelton. If you need mutly instances, you can just create instances by using `new BFRSA()` as many you want.

Comment: You might want to read on Java (or any other object oriented programming language) as a starting point. You will find your answer much quicker that way and will find answers to questions that you don't have right now but will have shortly.

Comment: It would also be more helpful if you posted more of your code. The one line you did post is useless.

Comment: "Constructor" was the word I'm looking for , would be more helpful in my search if I remember it earlier.I found the solution in @Erik P answer, thanks anyway. sorry for the ambiguity guys. I posted only one line as the code in both classes doesn't matter, I was trying to be exact in my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say you call a class, then you mean a constructor?

You can call hat constructor multiple times:

```
BFRSA bs1 = new BFRSA();
BFRSA bs2 = new BFRSA();
BFRSA bs2 = new BFRSA();
```

You can also iterate in a loop:

```
BFRSA bs;
for(int i = 1; i <= 10; i++){
    bs = new BFRSA();
}
```

If you need references to the objects created in the loop, you could add them to a `List`

Comment: Yes , "constructor" was the word I'm looking for , would be more helpful in my search if I remember it earlier.Anyway , the loop did the job, great work bro.Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Classes aren't functions. They can't be called. What you mean is instantiation, the creation of an object instance of the class. As long as the class's file is imported, where it is declared, and is of type `public`. You can instantiate an object of that class type within another class's declaration. The object has methods attached to it that can then be "called" to act on that object instance. Calling the constructor , i.e. `new ClassName ()` only creates more objects of that class. In addition the variable you have is a "pointer" to that object. A variable can only "point" to one object at a time.

Comment: Yes , "constructor" was the word I'm looking for , would be more helpful in my search if I remember it earlier.I found the solution in @Erik P answer, thanks anyway. sorry for the ambiguity.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you aren't brute-forcing. You're simply comparing how different public keys affect your plain text and you're probably trying to figure out a relation between these keys.

Now to the question.

*"The problem is I can only call BFRSA once with the same variable name."*

First of all, you cannot call a *class*. You can call *functions* and *constructors*. Probably you meant calling a constructor, but **where is the problem if you can call the constructor only once?** This is the design of all OOP based languages. *Constructors*, by design, are meant to be called only once. Their only purpose is to initialize the objects (in lay man's term, it  means giving birth to an object of species, say, BFRSA, with unique properties). *Functions* are meant to perform the real job. If you can think that way, you'll find it reasonable to not "give birth" to same object more than once.

If you still want to call a constructor more than once, perhaps your only option is to create a new language. ;)

Comment: You misunderstood the brute force method. I will make it simple for you: after the main encryption a second one is started n times applied on the same plain text, then comparing the new ciphered text with the old one, when they are equals , and the decryption results the right original plain text we preserve the parameters(p,q, e,d...) and the brute force attack is successful.For the constructor Erik already answered and it works no need for a new language ;)  , thanks for your interest.

Comment: Surely it will work, but what purpose does it serve? I never meant it will throw an error, but it's meaningless.

Comment: What I meant was that you can only call the constructor once **for a single object**. Erik's solution apparently seems like calling constructors multiple times, but you're actually creating a new object every time that constructor is called and reference to that old object is lost forever because you're using the same variable.

Comment: exactly, that's why Erik's solution is perfect because I'm applying an exhaustive search (comparison) here so using the old object deletion is good for memories usage optimization.My algorithm is not useless , I'm helping 4 persons with PhD making a detailed research on RSA algorithm.

Comment: I never commented on your algorithm. I'm sure your algorithm will be helpful (no sarcasm intended). What I'd like to say is it's actually upto JVM to optimize memory. Calling constructor multiple times on same variable will create a new object, which **doesn't necessarily mean old object will be killed.** Maybe JVM can do this, but you'll be doomed if you did this in C/C++.